# Preserve order of results when operating asynchronously on a list

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have an asynchronous function that processes requests from a list, but when each request is done, it's not ordered like before declared (since it's async). How can I fetch asynchronously but retain the original ordering?

Here's the fiddle http://jsbin.com/papunixume/edit?html,js,console

```
// clear console every single run
console.clear()

// create promise
const cp = (msg, timeout) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(msg)
    }, timeout)
  })
}

const a = cp('a', 1000)
const b = cp('b', 500)
const c = cp('c', 800)

Rx.Observable.of([a, b, c]).subscribe(val => {
  val.map(res => {
    res.then(x => console.log(x))
  })
})
```

Result is

```
"b"
"c"
"a"
```

Expected

```
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

Comment: What's the point of asynchronous processing if you want the calls in exact order? Maybe, if you could tell us what you are trying to achieve, we may help you come up with an idea.

Comment: you need to break it up so you Fetch each resource asynchronously, then use `Promise.all` to wait for all the fetching to complete; then process the resources in the order you want.

Comment: You don’t need RxJS for this: `Promise.all([a, b, c])`

Comment: yeah I think `Promise.all` enough to do this. Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on what and how you need to work with the Promises. What you have now doesn't need RxJS at all because you're just creating an array of Promises and then calling `then()` on each of them.

If you want to do in more "RxJS way" you can collect results from the Promises as they arrive while maintaining the same order with the `concatMap()` operator:

```
Rx.Observable.from([a, b, c])
  .concatMap(promise => promise)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

The magic happens inside `concatMap()` because it recognizes an instance of a Promise class and handles them in a special way (chains them with `then()` and reemits theirs result).

See demo: http://jsbin.com/gobayoy/4/edit?js,console

Or you can wait until all of the Promises complete and then emit all their results as a single array with `forkJoin()`:

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin(a, b, c)
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

See demo: http://jsbin.com/zojuya/2/edit?js,console

Again, RxJS handles Promises automatically so `forkJoin()` is able to wait for all Promises to finish without you worrying about it.

Comment: Thanks @martin. Also `Promise.all` I think enough to anyone who don't use RxJS 