# Preserve the order of the http calls in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to solve the order problem I'm facing with several approaches that I found here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886224/preserve-order-of-results-when-operating-asynchronously-on-a-list?rq=1) without a success.

I have a method, where I'm loading some data for an array of [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/index.html) layers:

```
private loadSelectedTileLayersCapabilities(): void {

        let tempTileLayer;

        this.selectedTileLayerIds.forEach(
            (selectedTileLayer: string) => {
                tempTileLayer = this.getTileLayerById(selectedTileLayer);

                this.capabilitiesService.getTileLayerDimensions(tempTileLayer.url, tempTileLayer.name, tempTileLayer.id)
                .subscribe(
                    dimensions => this.displayNewTileLayer(dimensions)
                );
            }
        );
    }
```

And then I have a method, where the `http` call is happening:

```
public getTileLayerDimensions(urlToFormat: string, tileLayerName: string, tileLayerId: string): Observable<Dimensions> {

        const capabilitiesUrl = `serviceUrl`;

        return this.httpClient.get(capabilitiesUrl, {responseType: "text"})
            .map(res => {

                // Doing stuff with data

                return dataForLayer;
            });

    }
```

The problem is, the `displayNewTileLayer(dimensions)` method is called in random order. Is there a way to preserve the order in which the items were stored in 
`selectedTileLayerIds` array?

Comment: just out of curiousity..is there a reason why you dont send all ids as an array in a single request and get an array in response?

Comment: This is how our service is made. It can handle one layer at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the http-calls are asynchronous, the responses may *not* arrive in the same order the requests were made. What you could do is to create a list of requests, create a [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) and wait for all responses to resolve. You can then call the `displayNewTileLayer(dimensions)`-method for all responses.

Here is an example

```
    const httpCalls = []; // store the requests here
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      httpCalls.push(this.http.get('someUrl').map(response => response));
    }
    forkJoin(httpCalls).subscribe(res => {
      // all responses completed. returns an array of data (one for each response).
      console.log('res', res);
    });
```

In you case, this code may work: (code not tested, and you may have to import the forkJoin operator in your code)

`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';`

```
private loadSelectedTileLayersCapabilities(): void {

    let tempTileLayer;
    let requests = []:

    this.selectedTileLayerIds.forEach(
        (selectedTileLayer: string) => {
            tempTileLayer = this.getTileLayerById(selectedTileLayer);
            const request = this.capabilitiesService.getTileLayerDimensions(tempTileLayer.url, tempTileLayer.name, tempTileLayer.id)
            requests.push(request);

        }
    );
    forkJoin(requests).subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(dimension => this.displayNewTileLayer(dimension));
    })
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it's working! Thank you! In `forEach` tho you have an error. It should be: `res.forEach(dimension => this.displayNewTileLayer(dimension));`

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for the comment, and glad it worked. I fixed my error.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider to use the `concat` operator.

Your code would look like the following

```
    private loadSelectedTileLayersCapabilities(): void {

            let tempTileLayer;
            let concatObs;

            this.selectedTileLayerIds.forEach(
                (selectedTileLayer: string) => {
                    tempTileLayer = this.getTileLayerById(selectedTileLayer);

                    const httpCall = this.capabilitiesService.getTileLayerDimensions(tempTileLayer.url, tempTileLayer.name, tempTileLayer.id);
                    if (!concatObs) {
                        concatObs = httpCall);
                     } else {
                         concatObs.concat(httpCall);
                     }

                }
            );
            concatObs.subscribe(
                dimensions => this.displayNewTileLayer(dimensions)
            );
        }
```

This way concatObs emits in the same order as the array `selectedTileLayersIds`. You should consider though if it is possible to move the sequencing logic to the server, i.e. have a service that receives an array of ids (`selectedTileLayersIds`) and returns and array of dimensions. In this way you would reduce the network traffic and avoid having a chain of sequential synchronous http calls.