# equivalent of redux 'getState' in from an observable in rxjs

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm having a play around with rxjs with the intention of getting to grips with reactive and functional programming in JS.

I have the following trivial app:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs'

const domContainer = document.querySelector('[data-container]')

const clickElement = document.querySelector('[data-init-fetch]')
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader')

// only emit when all the data is returned
const fetchData = (first, last) => Rx.Observable.range(first, last)
  .flatMap(async n => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${n}`)
    return await res.json()
  })
  .reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], [])

const createEventStream = ({
  domNode,
  createRequestDataAction,
  createReceiveDataAction,
}) => {

  const handleButtonClick = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(domNode, 'click')

  const request = fetchData(1, 10)
  // i'd like to be be able to 'getState' in here to use correct offset and 
  // fetch the next ten entries

  const setIsFetching = handleButtonClick
    .map(createRequestDataAction)

  // fetch data on request
  const requestData = handleButtonClick
    .switchMapTo(request)
    .map(createReceiveDataAction)

  return Rx.Observable.merge(
    requestData,
    setIsFetching,
  )
}

const initState = {
  offset: 1,
  isFetching: false,
  chars: {},
}

const eventStream = createEventStream({
  domNode: clickElement,
  createReceiveDataAction,
  createRequestDataAction,
})
  .scan(reducer, initState)
  .subscribe(
    renderMarkup,
  )

function reducer (
  state = initState,
  {
    type,
    payload,
  }
) {
  // do some reducery stuff in here and return new state
}

function renderMarkup(state) {
  // renders the state to the DOM
}

function createReceiveDataAction(data) {
  return {
    type: 'apiReceive',
    payload: {
      chars: data,
    },
  }
}

function createRequestDataAction() {
  return { type: 'apiRequest' }
  // this action will update offset += 10 in the reducer
}
```

My question is this, if I were using redux (although I'm not here) when I dispatch my fetchData action I would simply call getState() to get `offset` from the current state and use that in the `fetchData` action.

Is there a way to do this with rxjs (and without redux) in the above code? eg I would want to use variables from state in the `fetchData` call.

Would I need to create another Observable to deal with `offset`? Or am I approaching this in entirely the wrong way?

Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

I have though few comments that may help you.

**Use Observable instead of Promise**

You can convert this code

```
const fetchData = (first, last) => Rx.Observable.range(first, last)
  .flatMap(async n => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${n}`)
    return await res.json()
  })
  .reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], [])
```

to this

```
const fetchData = (first, last) => Rx.Observable.range(first, last)
  .mergeMap(n => {   // mergeMap is the new name of flatMap
    const promiseCall = fetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${n}`)
    return Observable.fromPromise(promiseCall).map(res => res.json())
  })
  .reduce((acc, item) => [...acc, item], [])
```

You may also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377607/preserve-the-order-of-the-http-calls-in-angular/49378509#49378509) to find other ways to execute many http requests and return only when all of them have completed.

**In eventStream you store a subscription**

If you run the following code you end up storing a Subscription in the variable eventStream. A Subcription instance can then be used to unsubscribe.

```
const eventStream = createEventStream({
  domNode: clickElement,
  createReceiveDataAction,
  createRequestDataAction,
})
  .scan(reducer, initState)
  .subscribe(
    renderMarkup,
  )
```

**Use state information in fetchData call**

I assume you store state information in the object referenced by the `state` variable.

If this is correct, I would proceed with something along these lines

```
const createEventStream = ({
  domNode,
  createRequestDataAction,
  createReceiveDataAction,
}) => {

  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(domNode, 'click')
    .map(createRequestDataAction)
    .concat(fetchData(initState.offset, initState.offset + 10))
    .map(createReceiveDataAction)

}
```

You could even think to remove the `reduce` function with something like this.

```
const createEventStream = ({
  domNode
}) => {

  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(domNode, 'click')
    .do(_ => state.fetching = true)
    .concat(fetchData(initState.offset, initState.offset + 10))
    .do(_ => initState.offset = initState.offset + 10)
    .do(_ => initState.fetching = false)

}
```

I could not test my recommendation, so I am not really sure there are no mistakes.

Comment: thanks for that.  Re what I'm trying to achieve, I'd be trying to access state to use in the `fetchData` call.  So that i can call `fetchData(offset, offset + 10)` and retrieve the next 10 entries from the api.  In redux actions I get `dispatch` and `getState` that I can call to retrieve the current state (or the offset).  However, I'm not using redux here. I'd like to access the state passed to the reducer as part of the eventStream.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think that's the best we can do in this situation.  My code above is for merely getting to grips with rxJs. I understand that in a real life situation this probably wouldn't be done in such a manner.  Thanks for your input.