# Angular: handle subscriptions on an array in a loop

Tags: angular, subscriptions

**What I want to do:**

I want to set on a list of objects multiple subscriptions to update the objects dynamically when the answer of the requests is complete.

**Problem:**

The Problem is at the moment, that in the for loop each element will overwrite the previous item with the subscription, so I get every time just the last subscription on all objects.

**The acutal code:**

```
// data list with hosts
let list = [
    {
        "name": "joe",
        "hosts": [
            {
                "name": "vlm01",
                "status": null,
                "update": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "hosts": [
            {
                "name": "vlm02",
                "status": null,
                "update": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "hosts": [
            {
                "name": "vlm03",
                "status": null,
                "update": null
            }
        ]
    }
]

// for loops to set a subscriber for each host
list.forEach(item => {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.hosts.length; i++) {
        this.statusHostService.getHostStatus().subscribe(result => item.hosts[i].status = result);
        this.statusHostService.getHostUpdateStatus().subscribe(result => item.hosts[i].update = result);
        this.hostService.startDeployment(host.name);
    };
});
```

In the service I do somthing like this:

```
private hostStatusSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
private hostStatusUpdateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

public getHostStatus() {
    return this.hostStatusSubject;
}

public getHostUpdateStatus() {
    return this.hostStatusUpdateSubject;
}

public startDeployment() {
    // load some config data then trigger the calls with the correct params
    this.loadHostStatus(url1, param1);
    this.loadHostStatusUpdate(url2, param2);
}

private loadHostStatus(url, param) {
    // load data over rest api
    this.hostStatusSubject.next(response);
}

private loadHostStatusUpdate(url, param) {
    // load data over rest api
    this.hostStatusUpdateSubject.next(response);
}
```

In my HTML code I have then a status view, which is watching on the subscribed results.
Do you have an idea how I have to do this in a "correct Angular way"?

**Solution by creating a new Instance of the Service**

```
// for loops to set a subscriber for each host
list.forEach(item => {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.hosts.length; i++) {
        // creation of a new instance from the service
        let service = new StatusHostService(this.statusHostService);
        service.getHostStatus().subscribe(result => item.hosts[i].status = result);
        service.getHostUpdateStatus().subscribe(result => item.hosts[i].update = result);
        this.hostService.startDeployment(host.name);
    };
});
```

But I will try to use the solution with forkJoin too.
When I have time I will integrate and test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve the order of the http calls in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377607/preserve-the-order-of-the-http-calls-in-angular)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried this already but may I used it wrong, but when I have a look on your linked article then I used it correct.
But the question here is, does it work with subscribers on subjects too or just on HTTP requests?
Because I use subjects in the service an not directly the HTTP request. In my case nothing happens in the forkJoin callback.

Comment: You can maintain a list of `Subject` as well (e.g. `mySubjects:Subject[] = [];`. It does not need to be HTTP-requests. And then you can add the requests/Subjects to your list. (e.g. `mySubjects.push(this.statusHostService.getHostStatus()`). And then you can do a forkJoin on the list of Subjects.

Comment: oh okay ty John, but I found the solution with just create a new instance of the service in the for-loop. I don't know if this is a very good solution but at the moment it works and does what it should.
I will edit the question above.